# How can I declare and use T-SQL variables across multiple SqlCommands using the same SqlConnection object to perform multiple inserts?

Tags: .net, sql-server-2005, variables, scope, sqlcommand

I want to load a list of records given a possibly lengthy list of usernames (anywhere from one to thousands of usernames).
Disregard how the name(s) are chosen, and assume they cannot be determined from any existing data in the database.  This applies to SQL Server 2005.

I specifically want to ***avoid*** using a **single select statement with thousands of expressions in the where clause**, which would result in an excessively lengthy command text for the SqlCommand object (e.g. `...where n='bob000001' or n='bob000002' or ... or n='bob003000'`).  Sounds reasonable?

I have decided to perform the select by populating a simple table variable with the usernames, then performing a select/join between the table variable and the table with the user data.

So, the first thing I need to do is populate the table variable.  I have some problems here:

- T-SQL syntax prior to SQL Server 2008 is verbose for inserting multiple rows into a table in a single statement, requiring something like [multiple selects and union alls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857120/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-once-to-a-table-in-sql-server-2005/857160#857160).
- Rather than use verbose syntax of SS2005, or even the terse syntax available in SQL Server 2008, I am avoiding lengthy command texts altogether and just using multiple commands over a single connection.
- Declaring a table variable in one SqlCommand, produces a "must declare the scalar variable" error when I try to use it in subsequent SqlCommands.
- Involving stored procedures in any way may still involve passing huge strings, or may prevent variables from persisting outside the scope of the stored procedure.  Assume creating stored procedures is not an option.

That third point is really the problem I'm trying to solve now.  I've seen examples where people (claim to) successfully declare and use a variable in a single SqlCommand without an error.  How can this be achieved when using multiple SqlCommand instances?  I read that variables will persist for a single connection across multiple commands.  Might involving a transaction help in some way?

Finally, keep in mind that I don't want to use temporary tables; doing so would offer a simple solution, but it also avoids the question I'm asking concerning variables and multiple SqlCommands; however, if you truly think that's the best option, feel free to say so.

Here is a code snippet that shows what's happening:

```
public static List<Student> Load( SqlConnection conn, List<StudentID> usernames )
{
    //Create table variable
    SqlCommand  command = new SqlCommand( "declare @s table (id varchar(30))", conn );
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    //Populate a table variable with the usernames to load
    command = new SqlCommand( "insert into @s (id) values (@p)", conn );
    command.Parameters.Add( "@p", SqlDbType.VarChar );
    int len = usernames.Count;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        command.Parameters["@p"].Value = usernames[i].ToString();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery(); //ERROR: must declare scalar variable @s
    }

    //Select all students listed in the table variable
    command = new SqlCommand( "select StudentID, FName, LName, [etc.] from Student inner join @s on StudentID = @s.id order by StudentID", conn );

    //Execute the query to get the student info from the database.
    List<Student> students = new List<Student>()
    using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
    {
        //code to load results and populate students list
    }
    return students;
}
```

Note: I'm aware that an SqlCommand involving parameters internally calls a stored procedure, which would normally prevent persisting variables across multiple SqlCommands, but the first query that declares the table variable doesn't involve parameters (i.e. no reference to command.Parameters.AddWithValue is made), so it should be in scope for later commands that may call stored procedures.

Edit: To use a temp table, one just has to change `@`s to `#`s and `declare @`s table" to `create table #`s, which is nice.  One may also want to drop the temp table at the end, but it's not necessary.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a temporary table which persists for the duration of the session/connection (multiple calls). Table variables have scope only for the batch, which is basically one call.

Comment: +1, table @variables are slower than #temp tables when you insert many rows, like the question says is going to happen

Comment: Would it really be slower than performing disc I/O to a temp-table, which also bothers the transaction log?  I'm considering that the table variable is only one column (I could make it varchar rather than char) and the size of the table may be relatively small.  The total length of all usernames is currently 32370 characters.  I am currently using a temp table, because I just had to change the '@' to a '#' to make it work, lol, but I'm still curious about how to deal with a variable persisting across SqlCommand calls without error.

Comment: I don't think you can. You also have to consider the performance when reading from the table variable. SQL keeps no stats and always assumed one row. You'd save on load but lose on later read.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with *lengthy command texts*? I've executed several kilobyte big query's in one call. SQL2005 supports it, and I think it's better than round-tripping all the time.

Why not create the query like this?

```
select StudentID, FName, LName, [etc.] from Student 
where StudentID in ('bob000001', 'bob000002', [etc.])
```

Comment: First of all, building up this request (by concatenating together string values) is prone to SQL injection. Also, if you call it repeatedly with different values, it's a different query every time, so SQL Server needs to find out a query plan every time. Using parameters allows SQL Server to create a query plan ONCE and then reuse that plan over and over again --> MUCH better for performance!

Comment: Yes, you're right, but concerning that you have all the information you need in the link provided in another answer below (by AlexK)

Comment: That is more concise than using where clauses, but suffers the same problems: a new query plan generated every time, and lots of string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but I believe you can batch multiple commands by wrapping them in a BEGIN/END block, and use a single call to run all of them.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how to solve your question, however my alternative approach to your problem would instead be to have a stored procedure that accepted a comma delimited list of ID's, inserted those ID's into a temporary table and then do a "SELECT WHERE IN", for example (altered from another blog):

```
CREATE PROC dbo.SelectStudents
(
    @StudentIdList varchar(8000)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    CREATE TABLE #StudentIdList (
        StudentId int,
    )

    DECLARE @StudentId varchar(10), @Pos int

    SET @StudentIdList = LTRIM(RTRIM(@StudentIdList)) + ','
    SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @StudentIdList, 1)

    IF REPLACE(@StudentIdList, ',', '') <> ''
    BEGIN
        WHILE @Pos > 0
        BEGIN
            SET @StudentId = LTRIM(RTRIM(LEFT(@StudentIdList, @Pos - 1)))
            IF @StudentId <> ''
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO #StudentIdList (StudentId) VALUES (CAST(@StudentId AS int))
            END
            SET @StudentIdList = RIGHT(@StudentIdList, LEN(@StudentIdList) - @Pos)
            SET @Pos = CHARINDEX(',', @StudentIdList, 1)
        END
    END 

    SELECT  * 
    FROM    dbo.Students
    WHERE   StudentId IN
    (
        SELECT StudentId FROM #StudentIdList
    )
END
```

You can then call this stored procedure with a comma delimtied list of id's:

```
exec dbo.SelectStudents '1,2'
```

You will need to make sure that your formatted list of id's is no longer than 8000 characters (and make multiple calls to the database if it is) however this method will be far more efficient and requires only a large parameter, not a long command text - making large numbers of trips to the database to insert each of the Id's will be **extremely** slow.

Similar approaches exist for passing in the list of Id's as Xml (although my preference would probably be to go for the simplicity of delimited strings).

Also, it shoud be possible to use the above technique even if for whatever reason you aren't able to create stored procedures on your database.

Comment: sql 2005+ supports n/varchar(max)

Comment: that is a slow way to split strings, there are much better ways: http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html

Comment: "Assume creating stored procedures is not an option." Yeah, I don't want to concatenate 10,000 usernames, only to split them again in a T-SQL stored procedure. The total character length of all usernames is already 32370, which is definitely more than 8000, and is likely to quadruple by September.

Comment: String manipulation is cheap, however round trips to the database and back are not! Not to mention that doing the inserts into the temporary table individually outside of a transaction prevents lock escalation which will have a large impact on performance.